# I'm interested in using Doctrine PHP ORM but does anyone know if the requirements need to be met on both a dev and a production server?

Tags: php, database, doctrine

I'm not sure if it's ok for me to run Doctrine on my dev machine, which, meets the minimum requirements of (PHP 5.3 and APC module) installed but not the production server which doesn't meet the requirements (PHP 5.2 and APC module not installed.)

Comment: The real project will run on the production server, won't it? So you have to support all used technologies on the Prod server.

Comment: Doctrine requires PHP 5.3 features such as namespaces to run which are not available in previous PHP versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to meet the requirements on both systems.